# Same body function works for different types of input c#

Tags: c#

I have a function  like this:

```
 void myFunc(String path)
{
SpecialObject special1 = new SpecialObject(path);

}
```

Now, my special object has several overloads of his constructor, like for example it can also take a stream as input.
How can avoid the need for another function like:

```
void myFunc(Stream stream)
{
SpecialObject special1 = new SpecialObject(stream);

}
```

EDIT:
SO here is the thing, I am doing a file processing routine, only function1 actually uses the Stream object, I want to lock the file on the duration of the mainFunction, so I thought that if open a file an keep it open will do the job, because I want to interference with this file:

```
mainFunction(string inputFile)
{
    Stream stream = new FileStream(inputFile,FileMode.Open);
    Function1();
    Function2();
    Function3();
    Function4();
    stream.Close();
}
```

Now Function1() is something like this:

```
Function1()
{
    PDFProcessor processor = new PDFProcessor();
    processor.addDataSrc(new PDFDataSource(STRING OR STREAM));
    processor.Work();
}
```

I could just use the Stream type.. but originally I used the string type.. and now I wanted to keep both.

Answer (score 4):

Put `myFunc` inside `SpecialObject`.  If all it cares about is the `SpecialObject`, make it a member function of it.

If that's not possible, have `myFunc` take a `SpecialObject` as its argument, that way you don't have to worry about constructing it.

Answer (score 1):

Have `myFunc` take a `SpecialObject` instead.  If I knew more about the situation, I might offer a different answer.

```
myFunc(new SpecialObject(path));
myFunc(new SpecialObject(stream));

void myFunc(SpecialObject special)
{
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you control the code for the input types you can use an interface or base class:

```
public interface ISpecialObjectCreateable { ... }

public MyClassA : ISpecialObjectCreateable { ... }

public MyClassB : ISpecialObjectCreateable { ... }

public class SpecialObject
{
    public SpecialObject(ISpecialObjectCreatable createable)
    {
       ...
    }
}
```

Now you can define `MyFunc` as:

```
void myFunc(ISpecialObjectCreateable createable)
{
    SpecialObject special1 = new SpecialObject(createable);

}
```

However, if you don't control the code for the input types (e.g. `string` or `Stream` types which are built into the framework), no you to avoid having overloads and maintain type-safety.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void myFunc (Stream aStream = null, String aString = null) {
    aStream?? processor.addDataSrc(new PDFDataSource(aString));
    aString?? processor.addDataSrc(new PDFDataSource(aStream));
}
```

In your client code you can use named parameters for clarity.

```
myFunc(aStream: thisStream);
myfunc(aString: thisString);
```

Of course we can throw `myFunc` a curve; will have to check that.

```
myFunc(thisStream, thisString);
```

Answer (score -2):

You could do

```
void myFunc(Object obj)
{
    SpecialObject special1 = null;
    if (obj is string)
        special1 = new SpecialObject(obj as string);
    else if (obj is Stream)
        special1 = new SpecialObject(obj as Stream);
}
```

You would need to handle the wrong object type being passed in.

Comment: This is just *awful* practice.